# why Allen Hatcher has mention the thick letter and thin letter?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I have some confusion in Allen Hatcher book

My confusion  is given below in red line

[image]

My confusion: what is thick letter and thin letter as  shown in figure ?

I didn't found the thick letter and thin letter.Im not getting  that why Allen Hatcher has mention the thick letter and thin letter ?

Comment: Perhaps it could be a blooper?

Comment: The letters are shown in previous figures iirc. Btw, a lot of people consider Hatcher's book quite a bit informal, so you might not necessarily like it.

Comment: "Thick" and "thin" letters are described on page 1.  A "thin" letter is a composed of one or more line segments or arcs (one-dimensional objects), while a "thick" letter is bounded by such a curve.